# Error Occur Implementing Movement Disorder API Following Apple Documentation

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

My team already get approved to use Movement Disorder Api "CMMovementDisorderManager". When i implement the code to fetch the result

Followings

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coremotion/monitoring_movement_disorders

```
guard CMMovementDisorderManager.isAvailable() else {

 // The movement disorder manager is not availble on this device.
    return

}
```

I am getting error

> {  "msg" : "Usage of CMMovementDisorderManager require a special
>   entitlement. Please see for more
>   https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coremotion/cmmovementdisordermanager","event","assert","condition","isEntitled"}

How I get this special entitlement. 
Help me out with this.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: on the website https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coremotion/cmmovementdisordermanager you shared, after the description there is an url Movement Disorder Entitlement Request ( https://developer.apple.com/contact/request/movement-disorder-api-entitlement/ )

Answer (score 0):

Sorry so late to answer. After receiving approval for the additional entitlement, you should create a new provisioning profile in your Developer Portal. In the process, you'll have the option add "additional entitlements" and the Movement Disorder entitlement will be available.
After creating the profiles (best I recall, I had to create three: app + watch + watch ext) you'll have to manually manage provisioning by selecting the correct profiles - I wasn't able to get "automatically manage signing" to work with an app using special entitlement.

Hope my late answer helps someone.

Comment: Thank you for Answer I already solved the issue which I was facing before.